# 1986 Nissan D21 Connector Part

Tags: electrical, nissan, alternator, connector

What is this?

As a hint, I'm losing about 2 volts between the alternator and the positive terminal of the battery here. It appears to be the last connection on the way back to the battery, just after the right headlight. It feels warm, so my guess is there's a short circuit here. Bonus points for where I can get a new one and how to install it.

Guesses:

- [Starter Relay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Starter-Relay-Standard-RY-132/282933857796?fits=Make%3ANissan%7CModel%3AD21&epid=1141229654&hash=item41e02c0e04:g:dmUAAOSw9~5ZS3sF) (oh wait, nevermind, that's the thing next to it in the second picture.)
- [Alternator Plug Harness](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AY1ZU0A)

[image: before utter destruction]
[image: same part, after I pried it apart]

Comment: Looks like a fuse link to me, a new one wont solve it, the connectors are corroded. Cleaning the male ones of corrosion is easy, cleaning the female ones are a challenge but can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Moab and confirmed by the guys at Napa, it's a fuse link. I bought 16-gauge fusible link wire to replace it.